# Struggling to append data to the buttons in array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create two buttons ("Correct" and "Wrong") for a simple quiz app.
I am also using a framework called snapKit to programmatically create the constraints of the buttons.
I would like to append the appropriate options to the two buttons in the array.
The error specifically is with the line
answerButtons.append(button)
I tried replacing this to
answerButtonsConstraints.append(button)
but alas this did not work.
Please see the code below.

```
private var answerButtons = [RoundedButton]()

var answerButtonsConstraints = [
    self.answerButtons[0].snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalTo(answerView)
        make.trailing.equalTo(answerView)
        make.top.equalTo(answerView)
        make.bottom.equalTo(answerButtons[1].snp.top).offset(-RightWrongQuizViewController.buttonPadding)
        make.height.equalTo(answerButtons[1])
        make.width.equalTo(answerButtons[1])
    },
    self.answerButtons[1].snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalTo(answerView)
        make.trailing.equalTo(answerView)
        make.bottom.equalTo(answerView)
    }
]

for index in 0...1 {
    let button = RoundedButton()
    answerButtons.append(button)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    answerView.addSubview(button)
    index == 0 ? button.setTitle("Correct", for: .normal) : button.setTitle("Wrong", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerButtonHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Edit 2:

I have an answerButton Handler which has the functionality which is implemented when the user clicks a button. Please see below

```
func answerButtonHandler(_ sender: RoundedButton) {
    timer.invalidate()

    if sender.titleLabel?.text == currentQuestion.correctAnswer {
        score += 1
        questionLabel.text = "Tap to continue"
        questionButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        sender.backgroundColor = flatRed
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        showAlert(forReason: 1)
    }

    for button in answerButtons {
        button.isEnabled = false
        if button.titleLabel?.text == currentQuestion.correctAnswer {
            button.backgroundColor = flatGreen
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a separate class which has the set up for my RoundedButton.

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

The requested stack trace looks like this....

```
2018-01-04 17:28:46.692 QuizGame(1)[40092:5544707] *** Terminating app 
due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to 
activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000272e40 
"QuizGame_1_.RoundedLabel:0x7fd3aff10640.top"> and 
<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x608000278a00 "UIView:0x7fd3aff0f240.top"> 
because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its 
anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's 
illegal.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106593b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105ff8141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001065fc625 + [NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000105b29d51 __55 + [NSLayoutConstraint _addOrRemoveConstraints:activate:]_block_invoke + 65
    4   Foundation                          0x0000000105b1a82b -[NSISEnginewithBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
    5   Foundation                          0x0000000105b162fa + [NSLayoutConstraint _addOrRemoveConstraints:activate:] + 420
    6   SnapKit                             0x0000000105a59386 _TFC7SnapKit10Constraint16activateIfNeededfT16updatingExistingSb_T_ + 2758
    7   SnapKit                             0x0000000105a6396b _TZFC7SnapKit15ConstraintMaker15makeConstraintsfT4itemPS_20LayoutConstraintItem_7closureFS0_T__T_ + 827
    8   SnapKit                             0x0000000105a6a1e3 _TFV7SnapKit17ConstraintViewDSL15makeConstraintsfFCS_15ConstraintMakerT_T_ + 99
    9   QuizGame(1)                         0x000000010592f219 _TFC11QuizGame_1_28RightWrongQuizViewController10setupViewsfT_T_ + 2121
    10  QuizGame(1)                         0x000000010592e831 _TFC11QuizGame_1_28RightWrongQuizViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 321
    11  QuizGame(1)                         0x000000010592e8a2 _TToFC11QuizGame_1_28RightWrongQuizViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010724301a -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1235
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001072493a6 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 118
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001072733c8 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1305
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000107283967 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 687
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000107284b41 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010747660c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010716355b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bb1c904 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bb10526 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 370
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bb103a0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ba9fe92 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    23  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bacc130 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 468
    24  QuartzCore                          0x000000010baccb37 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 115
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106539717 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106539687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010651e720 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010651e016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b346a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    30  UIKit                               0x00000001070a0134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    31  QuizGame(1)                         0x0000000105941f37 main + 55
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a3db65d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x000000010a6f1d42 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x000000010a729457 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
    frame #2: 0x000000010a48388f libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x000000010a258ce5 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 245
    frame #4: 0x000000010a273cbd libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 265
    frame #5: 0x0000000105ff83c4 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 103
    frame #6: 0x000000010a270f29 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x000000010a270bbe libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #8: 0x0000000105ff82dc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
    frame #9: 0x000000010651e096 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 534
    frame #10: 0x000000010b346a24 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #11: 0x00000001070a0134 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
  * frame #12: 0x0000000105941f37 QuizGame(1)`main at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #13: 0x000000010a3db65d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #14: 0x000000010a3db65d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Comment: What error do you get?  What's the declaration of `answerButtons` look like?

Comment: I receive a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, which is normally associated with outlets not being connected up correctly, however I am creating the views without storyboards so am unsure as to why I am receiving this error.

If I add the second line as mentioned above 
      

        answerButtonsConstraints.append(button)

I receive the warning "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

I have now edited the original message to include the declaration.

Comment: When you get SIGABRT, what does a stack trace look like?  (You can type "bt" at the (lldb) prompt.)  Also, is `RoundedButton` a subclass of `UIButton`?  If so, what button type do you use to init the superclass? (In other words, what does the init method of `RoundedButton` look like?)

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have edited the original message to hopefully include more information. I appreciate your patience, as I am a newbie :)

Comment: Sorry I edited again, as there was some confusion I think.

Comment: 1) The uncaught exception is related with some `RoundedLabel` topAnchor constraint that is not presented in your code. Check if it's added to superview before setting up the constraints.  2) `makeConstraints` adds constraints and returns `Void`, so your `answerButtonsConstraints` is in fact an array of Void. What was the purpose of it? 3) `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is managed by Snapkit automatically 4) You could use `equalToSuperview()` instead of `equalTo(answerView)` for all `answerView` subviews

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your response. You were absolutely right. I forgot to add my roundedLabel as a subview.

I appreciate your answer and tips greatly. Although it was a silly mistake it has helped me to learn the importance of attention to detail.

Thanks again.